# Different classes for Light

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Please explain the difference between the two classes.
"class gazebo::physics::Light" and "class gazebo::rendering::Light"

I want to turn on/off light dynamically using a gazebo model plugin. I am not sure which class and function should be used.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17381/different-classes-for-light/) by [Ash_100](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3901/ash_100/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2017-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For controlling any of the light's visible characteristics, use `rendering::Light`'s API.

Every light in Gazebo consists of a pair of objects, one in the rendering engine, and another in the physics server. The rendering object keeps track of everything related to how the light affects the world's appearance, while the physics object controls how the light moves, its speed and whether it is attached to other objects.

Actually, this "double personality" is not exclusive to lights. All visible entities in the world have both a representation in physics and in rendering. The difference is that for the rendering, they're all instances of `rendering::Visual`. You can check which physical entity they correspond to by calling [rendering::Visual::GetType](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1rendering_1_1Visual.html#ac142bc1964f63b4536874c7d68461c93) and that may return values such as `LINK` and `COLLISION`.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1